# COPY-ITEM Passthru not working when encountering error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Within ISE, I've tried both the below. Neither is working. The only way is to clear `$error` and test after the copy attempt. Any suggestions?

```
$cpy = Copy-Item -Path "D:\~a\2K0NVK0.xt" -Destination "D:\~Bkup-F\2K0NVK10.txt" -Force -passthru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($cpy){ $cpy   # only displays on successful copy }

Try{
  Copy-Item -Path "D:\~a\2K0NVK0.xt" -Destination "D:\~Bkup-F\2K0NVK10.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} Catch { write-host "Hit a bug!"   # not being displayed }
```

Comment: Instead of the passthru approach have you tried using `$?` e.g. `if ($?) {'success'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try/catch only works when ErrorAction is set to Stop.